# How always redirect at https://www.?

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5

How to make that my laravel 5.8 site always works with https://www. prefix ?
In .htaccess i wrote

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        RedirectMatch 404 /\.git

#       RewriteRule ^$ info.php [QSA]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But looks like RewriteRule is not applicable is some case when I run url like “mysite.com” browser redirects “https://mysitede.com”.
Also to be sure that I work https in my app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I have :

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    use funcsTrait;

    public function boot()
    {

        if( $this->isHttpsProtocol() ) {  // check I am not on local server
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
```

Which is the decision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following `.htaccess` code redirects requests to the https and www versions of your web pages. Add to your site's root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```